# im4Java, change frame colour?

Tags: java, imagemagick, im4java

How to change frame colour in ImageMagick 4 Java?
I have something like this, but frame is all the time white...

```
IMOperation miop = new IMOperation();
miop.background("#000000");
miop.addImage(path+fileName);
miop.colorize(5,21,64);
miop.frame(2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IMOperation miop = new IMOperation();    
miop.addImage(path+fileName);
miop.background("#000000");
miop.colorize(5,21,64);
miop.frame(2);
miop.addImage(newPath+fileName);
```

Solution.